# Centos find command enigma

Tags: linux, shell, unix, centos7

I have a directory structure like below (Centos 7 and Mac both same issue)

```
mkdir -p test/lemon-ip-ip/2020-04-08
mkdir -p test/king-ip-ip/2020-04-08
```

now I need to find only "test/lemon-ip-ip/2020-04-08" using the find command for this, I did this

```
find test/lemon-ip-ip -maxdepth 1 -name ????-??-??
```

this gives the right answer

```
test/lemon-ip-ip/2020-04-08
```

this is what I want and worked fine till now. However, when I created the directory "king-ip-ip/" this command

```
find test/king-ip-ip -maxdepth 1 -name ????-??-??
```

gives the wrong output

```
test/king-ip-ip/
test/king-ip-ip/2020-04-08
```

this is returning parent directly too "test/king-ip-ip/" this happens only with this specific string when I change the directory to say "test/king-ip/" again this works fine. I can't change the directory name. Could someone let me know what is causing this issue?

I need the final output to be

```
test/king-ip-ip/2020-04-08
```

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this is that the pattern `????-??-??` matches any 4, 2 and 2 characters with dashes in between. Such strings include `2020-04-08`, `aaaa-bb-cc` and `king-ip-ip`.

While you're not asking for alternatives, my suggestion would be one of these, depending on the details of how you're using it:

```
# Don't use find at all
echo test/king-ip-ip/????-??-??

# Only search files strictly inside the directory, not the dir itself
find test/king-ip-ip/* -maxdepth 0 -name '????-??-??'
find test/king-ip-ip   -maxdepth 1 -depth 1 -name '????-??-??'

# Only match numbers, not other characters
find test/king-ip-ip   -maxdepth 1 -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]'
```

Comment: I tried like this find test/king-ip-ip -name '^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})$' this doesn't work, just trying for compact answer. may there is some flag I need to use with find for regex?

Comment: You can use `-regex` to match a regex (against the whole path, not just the name), and `-regextype` to select the specific regex language you're using.